# Django export env error : not a valid identifier

Tags: python, django, linux

I'm coding in Django ,and want to export the env in build.sh ,the env is an email attachment file type list,I have put it in a python list in the build.sh like this:

```
export PROJECT_EMAIL_FILE_TYPE = [".txt", ".doc",".docx","xls","xlsx","csv",".pdf", ".jpg",".png", ".jpeg",".html",".ppt"]
```

Then I plan to call it from the settings.py

```
PROJECT_EMAIL_FILE_TYPE = os.environ.get('PROJECT_EMAIL_FILE_TYPE ')
```

And then called it any place I want by :

```
settings.AEGIS_EMAIL_FILE_TYPE
```

However when I export it by directly copy that line and enter in Linux there was an Error:

```
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `[.txt,': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `.doc,.docx,xls,xlsx,csv,.pdf,': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `.jpg,.png,': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `.jpeg,.html,.ppt]': not a valid identifier
```

Any friend can help ? How should I do this properly ?

Comment: Learn about bash (you didn't even tag this as bash). Don't use spaces around `=`. A list in bash is not a list as in Python. Create a single string, separated by comma's, then parse accordingly in Python (e.g. using `.split(',')`. Also, `build.sh` is a weird name for a file setting environment variables.

Comment: You also have an extra space in the Pyton code in the variable name. As a result, you're unlikely to retrieve the (correct) variable.

Comment: `settings.AEGIS_EMAIL_FILE_TYPE`?? What about `PROJECT_EMAIL_FILE_TYPE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shell script:

```
export PROJECT_EMAIL_FILE_TYPES=".txt,.doc,.docx,xls,xlsx,csv,.pdf,.jpg,.png,.jpeg,.html,.ppt"
```

In your Python code:

```
PROJECT_EMAIL_FILE_TYPES = os.environ.get('PROJECT_EMAIL_FILE_TYPES').split(',')
```

(Use proper variable names; here, for example, plural when the variable contains a list.)